# Where is "unix:abstract=/tmp/dbus-KtyPDgWNin" socket file saved?

Tags: linux, unix, sockets

I try the following:

```
roroco@roroco ~/Dropbox/rbs/ro_cmds $ echo $DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS
unix:abstract=/tmp/dbus-KtyPDgWNin,guid=ca3ea893cf45d42ef60e74d0545d84f6
```

But when I want to list this socket file, I can't seem to find it:

```
roroco@roroco ~/Dropbox/rbs/ro_cmds $ lsa /tmp/dbus-KtyPDgWNin
ls: cannot access /tmp/dbus-KtyPDgWNin: No such file or directory
```

Comment: If you know the socket (like 42133) try  the netstat -a command. Those sockets you are talking about are UNIX domain sockets.  netstat will show more information, if the socket is persistent.  Unix domain sockets usually have the socket number as part of the name: the uzposs1 process has this domain socket: uzposs1.unixstr10002

Answer (score 9):

It's an "abstract" socket;  it doesn't exist in the file system.  This is a Linux-ism.  See `man 7 unix` for more details.